# mkdir issue in bash function

Tags: bash, macos

I am trying to write a function in my .bash_profile that makes a directory and changes to it but I can't get it to work for some reason.

```
function mkdcd() {
    mkdir "$1" && cd "$1"
}
```

I get the error

```
mkdir: .: No such file or directory
```

I've made this function before on a different computer and it works, so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong this time.

Comment: Which platforms?

Comment: @aryamccarthy what do you mean by platform?

Comment: The function works properly for me.  Looks like your current directory is the issue. i.e., you seem to be invoking the function after removing your current directory.  Add this to the function to verify: `[[ -d $PWD ]] || { echo no current dir >&2; exit 1; }`

Comment: @codeforester how am I removing my current directory? Also should I add that before or after what I have?

Comment: I am saying that based on the error you have posted.

Comment: @codeforester adding in that check doesn't change the result

Comment: I have no issue using this code as long as I pass an argument to `mkdcd`.

Comment: @aryamccarthy The code itself is fine but for some reason it was interpreting the name of the function as `mkdir` or something like that because all I did was change the name and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really don't know why this is the case but I changed the name from `mkdcd` to `mkcd` and it fixed my issue.

Thanks to all the people that tried to help!

Answer (score -1):

You cannot alias those commands together directly with logic operators. Try using this approach instead

```
function mkdcd() {
    mkdir -p -- "$1" &&
    cd -P -- "$1"
}
```

Comment: that didn't fix anything unfortunately